# Define variables local to a JavaScript class

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do we define variables specific to the scope of JavaScript class?

In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zmyLwtc0/1/) below, I would like to define a variable called `name` specific to the class `Person`. I am getting an error `SyntaxError: missing : after property id`

```
var Person = {
   var name = "Jake";
   printName: function()
   {
    document.getElementById("personName").val(this.name);
   }
};

Person.printName();
```

Comment: `Person` is an **object**, not a class. Objects can only have properties. They don't have a concept of "local variables".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating `Person` wrongly and `val()` is not a javascript method. Try like following.

```js
var Person = {
  name: "Jake",
  printName: function() {
    document.getElementById("personName").value = this.name;
  }
};

Person.printName();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="personName">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in how you wrote your code.

You've defined `Person` as an object while trying to use full JavaScript statements like `var name = "jake";`. Objects take key and value pairs. So the correct way to write the block is this:

```
var Person = {
   name: "Jake",
   printName: function() {
     document.getElementById("personName").value = this.name;
   }
};

Person.printName();
```

If you are looking to create a "class" of person, the alternate syntax you want to consider is:

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.printName = function() {
    document.getElementById("personName").value = this.name;
  }
}

var jake = new Person("Jake");

jake.printName();
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: `.val(this.name);` is jQuery.

Comment: Try `.value = this.name`;

Answer (score 1):

You could use a closure to simulate private properties.

```
function createPerson() {
  var name = 'Jake';

  return {
    printName: function() {
      return name;
    }
  };
}

var person = createPerson();
console.log(person.printName); // prints 'Jake'
console.log(person.name); // prints undefined
console.log(name) // throws 'Undefined variable' error
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to use jQuery:

```
var Person = {
  name: "Jake",
  printName: function() {
    $("#personName").val(this.name);
  }
};
Person.printName();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zmyLwtc0/2/

*`val()` is a jQuery method for the Element Object. In JS we use the attribute `value` instead.